# Find integers $r$, $s$, and $t$ such that $12r + 30s + 18t = 2$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Could someone please explain if such integers exist and how to find them? If not, could someone please explain how to prove that they don't exist? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

They don't. The LHS is divisible by $3$ whereas the RHS isn't.

Comment: My professor said that there's a proof in which if you add a multiple of k with a multiple k you should get a multiple of k. Is that how we prove that such integers do not exist? Since you're adding multiples of 3 on the left, we expect a multiple of 3 on the right, but 2 is not a multiple of 3.

Comment: Yes, one way is to observe that $12r$, $30s$ and $18t$ are each divisible by $3$. Another is via writing $12r+30s+18t=3(4r+10s+6t)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\ Hint: $
If such integer exist, then 
                              $$6r + 15s + 9t = 1$$

so                             $$3\,(2r + 5s + 3t) = 1,$$
 and this is an absurd.